# login form keeps telling my username already exists django

Tags: python, django, forms

So I am trying to make a login form for a django website using a forms.py file to generate a form in my html. I have already made a registration form using the same methods and that works fine but for some reason my login form keeps working like a registration form and saying that my username already exists. i assume it is just a litle mistake but I can't figure out what it is exactly.

#### forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'password']
```

#### models.py

```
class LoginFormView(View):
form_class = LoginForm
template_name = 'intranet/login_form.html'

def get(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(None)
    return render(request,self.template_name,{'form': form})

def post(self,request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():

        username = request.POST.get['username']
        password = request.POST.get['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                return redirect('werknemers_list')

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

#### login_form.html

```
<h1>Log in</h1>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="log in" />
</form>
```

#### urls.py

```
 from django.conf.urls import  url

    from intranet import views

    urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^$', views.LoginFormView.as_view(), name='login'),
      url(r'^registreer$', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='registreer')]
```

Comment: Please post the urls.py for the registration and login view

Comment: Here you go, I added it to the question

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a ModelForm for this. That will always call the model validation, which in this case checks for username uniqueness.

Use a standard Form class instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot this was just what I needed.